# Does any Hindu scriptures mention anything about Jesus Christ?

Tags: bhavishya-purana, non-hindu

Does any hindu scripture mention anything about Jesus Christ ? In Bhavishya Purana may be ?

Answer (score 1):

The description that is taken to be of Jesus is found in verses 17-32 in the 19th chapter of the Chaturyuga Khanda Dvitiyadhyayah of the Bhavishya Purana.:

Texts 17 - 21

> vikramaditya-pautrasca
> pitr-rajyam grhitavan
> jitva sakanduradharsams
> cina-taittiridesajan
>
> bahlikankamarupasca
> romajankhurajanchhatan
> tesam kosan-grhitva ca
> danda-yogyanakarayat
>
> sthapita tena maryada
> mleccharyanam prthak-prthak
> sindhusthanam iti jneyam
> rastramaryasya cottamam
>
> mlecchasthanam param sindhoh
> krtam tena mahatmana
> ekada tu sakadiso
> himatungam samayayau
>
> “Ruling over the Aryans was a king called Shalivahana, the grandson of Vikramaditya, who occupied the throne of his father. He defeated the Shakas who were very difficult to subdue, the Cinas [Chinese], and the people from Tittiri and Bahikaus who could assume any form at will. He also defeated the people from Rome and the descendants of Khuru, who were deceitful and wicked. He punished them severely and took their wealth. Shalivahana thus established the boundaries dividing the separate countries of the mlecchas [low classes] and the Aryans. In this way Sindusthan came to be known as the greatest country. That personality appointed the abode of the mlecchas beyond the Sindhu River and to the west.”

Text 22

> ekadaa tu shakadhisho
> himatungari samaayayau
> hunadeshasya madhye vai
> giristhan purusam shubhano
> dadarsha balaram raajaa
>
> Once upon a time the subduer of the Sakas went towards Himatunga and in the middle of the Huna country (Hunadesh - the area near Manasa Sarovara or Kailash mountain in Western Tibet), the powerful king saw an auspicious man who was living on a mountain. The man’s complexion was golden and his clothes were white.

Text 23

> ko bharam iti tam praaha
> su hovacha mudanvitah
> **iishaa purtagm** maam viddhi
> kumaarigarbha sambhavam
>
> “The king asked, ‘Who are you sir?’ ‘You should know that **I am Isha Putra,** the Son of God’, he replied blissfully, and ‘am born of a virgin.’”

Text 24

> **mleccha dharmasya** vaktaram
> satyavata paraayanam
> iti srutva nrpa praaha
> dharmah ko bhavato matah
>
> “‘I am the expounder of the **religion of the mlecchas** and I strictly adhere to the Absolute Truth.’ Hearing this the king enquired, ‘What are the religious principles according to your opinion?’

Texts 25 - 26

> shruto vaaca mahaaraaja
> praapte satyasya samkshaye
> nirmaaryaade mlechadeshe
> masiiho 'ham samagatah
>
> iishaamasii ca dasyuunaa
> praadurbhuutaa bhayankarii
> taamaham mlecchataah praapya
> masiihatva mupaagatah
>
> “Hearing this questions of Shalivahana, Isha putra said, ‘O king, when the destruction of the truth occurred, I, Masiha the prophet, came to this country of degraded people where there are no rules and regulations. Finding that fearful irreligious condition of the barbarians spreading from Mleccha-Desha, I have taken to prophethood’.”

Texts 27 - 29

> mlecchasa sthaapito dharmo
> mayaa tacchrnu bhuupate
> maanasam nirmalam krtva
> malam dehe subhaasbham
>
> naiganam apamasthaya
> japeta nirmalam param
> nyayena satyavacasaa
> manasyai kena manavah
>
> dhyayena pujayedisham
> suurya-mandala-samsthitam
> acaloyam prabhuh sakshat-
> athaa suuryacalah sada
>
> “Please hear, Oh king, which religious principles I have established among the mlecchas. The living entity is subject to good and bad contaminations. The mind should be purified by taking recourse of proper conduct and performance of japa [meditation on the chanting of the holy names of God]. By chanting the holy names one attains the highest purity. Just as the immovable sun attracts, from all directions, the elements of all living beings, the Lord of the Surya Mandala [solar planet], who is fixed and all-attractive, and attracts the hearts of all living creatures. Thus by following rules, speaking truthful words, by mental harmony and by meditation, Oh descendant of Manu, one should worship that immovable Lord’.”

Text 30

> **isha muurtirt**-dradi praptaa
> nityashuddha **sivamkari
> ishamasihah** iti ca
> mama nama pratishthitam
>
> **“Having placed the eternally pure and auspicious (Shiva) form of the Supreme Lord (Isha) in my heart, O protector of the earth planet, I preached these principles through the mlecchas’ own faith and thus my name became ‘isha-masiha’.”**

Text 31

> iti shrutra sa bhuupale
> natraa tam mlecchapujaam
> sthaapayaamaasa tam tutra
> mlecchasthaane hi daarune
>
> “After hearing these words and paying obeisances to that person who is worshiped by the wicked, the king humbly requested him to stay there in the dreadful land of mlecchas.”

Text 32

> svaraajyam praaptavaan raajaa
> hayamedhan ciikirat
> raajyam kriitvaa sa shashthyabdam
> svarga lokamu paayayau
>
> “King Shalivahana, after leaving his kingdom performed an asvamedha yajna and after ruling for sixty years, went to heaven. Now please hear what happened when the king went to (the heavenly region of) svargaloka.”

Thus ends the second chapter entitled, “The Age of Shalivahana” of the story of Kali Yuga of the Chaturyuga Khanda also called Pratisarga-parva of the wonderful Bhavishya Maha Purana.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Answer (score 0):

Bhavishya Purana has Jesus as a devotee of Lord Vishnu -

> “**Please hear Oh king which religious principles I have established
> among the mlecchas.** The living entity is subject to good and bad
> contaminations. The mind should be purified by taking recourse of
> proper conduct and performance of japa. **By chanting the holy names
> one attains the highest purity**. (Jesus too prayed to his father: o
> holy father, hallowed be thy name) Just as the immovable sun attracts,
> from all directions, the elements of all living beings, the Lord of
> the solar region, who is fixed and all-attractive, attracts the hearts
> of all living creatures. Thus by following rules, speaking truthful
> words, by mental harmony and by meditation, **Oh descendant of Manu,
> one should worship that immovable Lord Vishnu**.”’ “**Having placed
> the eternally pure and auspicious form of the Supreme Lord Vishnu in
> my heart, O protector of the earth planet, I preached these principles
> through the Mlecchas’ own faith and thus my name became ‘isha-masiha’
> (Jesus the Messiah).”**

- Pratisarga parva, Bhavishya Purana.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note. There is no mention that Jesus is a devotee as per the scriptures. It is no where mentioned as such. It is not mentioned that he was actually son of God, or that he was an authorised prophet. He preached himself as God, and excluded other religions.
From this it is evident he is misguiding, as a devotee of Shri Vishnu would never engage in unreligious actions like eating beef and replacing Vishnu’s worship with one’s own.